# Insert Polymer elements and scripts in a .Jade file

Tags: node.js, pug, polymer

I don't know how to insert Polymer tags and UI components to Jade file, how to render it, or how to add the necessary script on the site. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you can explain what you have tried, and where you are failing, it will help us help you!

Comment: of course! 
I followed by http://www.clock.co.uk/blog/a-simple-website-in-nodejs-with-express-jade-and-stylus

So basicly I have working template. Now I installed a Polymer and I wanna use it inisde layaout.jade file but i dont know how to put <paper-button>flat button</paper-button> into layout.jade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load up webcomponents polyfills

```
script(src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js")
```

Import Polymer and the element you want to use.

```
link(rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html")
link(rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html")
```

Then create instances of it in your jade template.

```
paper-button() flat button
paper-button(raised) raised button
paper-button(noink) No ripple effect
```